# Setting Dokku environment variables

Tags: dokku

I'm trying to set Some variables on Dokku for deployment. As far as i can see from the dev files, one should create a .env file in the directory and put the variables in there. But this is not updating anything

.env file

```
DOKKU_NGINX_PORT=3000
MYSQL_URL=http://blabla
MYSQL_USER=mysqluser
```

I'm trying to map the port of the app to port 3000, and inject the mysql vars into the runtime environment.

I know I can set it with dokku config:set on the server, but I want to be able to automate it during deployment.

Any ideas? Or an example?

Answer (score 6):

### You'll need to install a Dokku client, or CLI in order to locally interact with the remote application on your Dokku instance.

Here are a few options:

- #### (node.js) dokku-toolbelt

  > Dokku toolbelt is a node-based CLI wrapper that proxies requests to
  >   the Dokku command running on remote hosts.

You can install it via the following shell command (assuming you have node and npm installed):

```
$ npm install -g dokku-toolbelt
```

*See [documentation here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dokku-toolbelt) for more information.*

- #### (python) dokku-client

  > Dokku client is an extensible python-based cli wrapper for remote
  >   Dokku hosts.

You can install it via the following shell command (assuming you have python and pip installed):

```
$ pip install dokku-client
```

*See [documentation here](https://github.com/adamcharnock/dokku-client) for more information.*

- #### (ruby) Dokku CLI

  > Dokku CLI is a rubygem that acts as a client for your Dokku
  >   installation.

You can install it via the following shell command (assuming you have ruby and rubygems installed):

```
$ gem install dokku-cli
```

*See [documentation here](https://github.com/SebastianSzturo/dokku-cli) for more information.*

---

### After the Dokku client is installed locally, make sure that the dokku app remote is set inside the repository directory.

You can verify this by running `$ git remote -v`.

If the output doesn't show your dokku application instance, set it with the following command:

```
$ git remote add dokku dokku@example.com:your-app-name
```

Here's an example from my terminal with some information redacted for security purposes.

```
    seth@linuxmint ~/repos/Adopt-a-Pet $ git remote -v
    dokku   dokku@example.com:adopt-a-pet (fetch)
    dokku   dokku@example.com:adopt-a-pet (push)
    origin  https://github.com/sethbergman/Adopt-a-Pet.git (fetch)
    origin  https://github.com/sethbergman/Adopt-a-Pet.git (push)
```

Then you can set environment variables with the following commands:

```
$ dokku config:set DOKKU_NGINX_PORT=3000
```

You can optionally set environment variables with the `.env` file:

```
$ dokku config:set:file <path/to/.env>
```

If the `.env` file is in the root directory of the repository, then the command would be:

```
$ dokku config:set:file <.env>
```

Comment: This does not at all answer the original question. OP asked how to get environment variables picked up automatically from a file, not how to set them manually given a file...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ruby, you can use the gem 'dokku-cli'. With that, you can set config from any file by issuing the command

```
dokku config:set:file <path/to/file>
```

See [ruby doc](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/dokku-cli/0.2.0)