# Dokku (Heroku) bulk set environment variables ("config vars")

Tags: heroku, environment-variables, config, dokku

[Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) indicate that "On a traditional host or when working locally, you often set environment variables in your .bashrc file. On Heroku, you use config vars". On Dokku the process is analogous: https://dokku.com/docs/configuration/environment-variables/

With the "traditional" method I can take a .env file append it's contents to .bashrc over ssh with a single automated standard unix command.

The Heroku docs only describe how to set "config vars" one by one. It would take unacceptably long to do this.

On Heroku one could perhaps use the api. But Dokku does not have an API.

Question is similar to [Setting Dokku environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47574896/setting-dokku-environment-variables)
The accepted answer there speaks about a local CLI for dokku where you can run `$ dokku config:set:file <path/to/.env>`. I can't find documentation on this command with "standard" dokku. I don't need a local CLI I can ssh and scp to my server.

Question is similar to [Bulk set the environment variables in Heroku pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58946075/bulk-set-the-environment-variables-in-heroku-pipeline) except that I don't know what a Heroku pipeline is and I'm not using one (and the question has no answer).

Is there a mechanism short of creating a bash script or installing a local Dokku CLI for bulk updating config vars in Heroku based on a .env file with a long list of variables?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use `heroku config:set ENV_ONE=value ENV_TWO=value ENV_THREE=value` from the heroku CLI in your terminal.
Make sure it's all a single line, use spaces, not line breaks.